# How can I detect plane and add model entity on it in visionOS?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit, visionos

I want to detect the plane in visionOS and want to ray cast from center of screen and if there is plane available then place a model entity on that position.

What I want to do is add the same feature into visionOS that we do with RealityKit in iOS.